# Automatic Service Recovery (Linux)

Tags: linux, centos

**What is an easy convenient automatic service recovery option?**

Basically if for example iptables stops I wish it to be automatically start soon after. I would like to apply this to 6-10 services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have used [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) in the past. Its syntax looks like this:

```
check process sshd with pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
   start program  "/etc/init.d/ssh start"
   stop program  "/etc/init.d/ssh stop"
   if failed port 22 protocol ssh then restart
   if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Now we use the processes capabilities of [CFengine](http://www.cfengine.org) to restart/kill processes for a very broad range of reasons, but you need to have an existing CFengine infrastructure to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for daemontools (http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html - "supervise" command) or runit (http://smarden.org/runit/)

Comment: I'd like to avoid runit  as I've read about some stability issues. I will check out daemon tools.

Comment: I've been running daemontools in production for a long time.  Solid stuff.  The daemon has to run in the foreground to work with daemoontools, which would not be suitable for "iptables."  iptables allows you to enter rules into netfilter in the kernel and is not a daemon.